# How to add a point counter to a quiz that subtracts 0.5 points on the second attempt if it is correct

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

first time slack oveflow user here. I'm in a beginner CS course using python and was tasked with creating a quiz that checks the user's answer for correctness using an if/­else structure. If the user answers correctly, inform the user and assign full points. Otherwise, allow the user a second attempt and provide half the points if they answer correctly and zero if they dont. I've pasted two questions from my quiz as an example.

```
score = 0

#Q1 Multiple Choice
for tries in range(2):
    print("\n", "QUESTION 1:", "\n", "Which of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state? Input a Letter A-E ")
    print(" a) Anabolism", "\n", "b) Catabolism", "\n", "c) Tolerance", "\n", "d) Homeostasis", "\n", "e) Metabolism")
    answer1 = input("Make your choice: ")
    if answer1 == "D" or answer1 == "d" :
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1 # full points given if correct on first attempt
        break
    else:
        print("False!")
        score = score + 0.5 # 0.5 points deducted if correct on second attempt
else:
    print("Out of chances! Sorry you are incorrect, Homeostasis (answer D) describes the body’s ability to maintain its normal state.”")
    score = score + 0 # no points given if second attempt was wrong 
    
#Q2 Numeric Response
for i in range(2):
    print("QUESTION 2")
    answer = input("How many organ systems are in the human body? Please enter an integer:") 
    
    if answer == "11":
        print("Correct, there are 11 organ systems in the body.The 11 systems are Integumentary System, Skeletal System, Muscular System, Nervous System, Endocrine System, Cardiovascular System, Lymphatic System, Respiratory System Digestive System, Urinary System, and Reproductive System")
        score = score + 1
        break;
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
    if(i == 1):
        print("answer = 11")
        score = score + 0.5

print("you scored",score, "points")
```

I added the score = score +1 which works but it does not subtract the 0.5 on the second attempt but instead just adds all the points up regardless of correctness. I tried to add another if else statement to say if they got it wrong after a second attempt then assign zero points then the 0.5 if they got it correct but i believe there's an easier way to add that without using a million if else statements but I just can't figure it out. I'm not receiving any error messages just an incorrect calculation, i believe it has to do with either how i'm formatting it or where i'm placing the score calculations under the print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your existing code like:

```
score = 0

# Q1 Multiple Choice
for tries in range(2):
    print("\nQUESTION 1:\nWhich of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state? Input a Letter A-E ")
    print("a) Anabolism\nb) Catabolism\nc) Tolerance\nd) Homeostasis\ne) Metabolism")
    answer1 = input("Make your choice: ").strip().upper()  # Ensure case insensitivity
    
    if answer1 == "D":
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1  # Full points given if correct on first attempt
        break
    else:
        print("False!")
        if tries == 1:
            print("Out of chances! Sorry you are incorrect, Homeostasis (answer D) describes the body’s ability to maintain its normal state.")
            break
        else:
            print("Second attempt.")
            score += 0.5  # 0.5 points deducted if correct on second attempt

# Q2 Numeric Response
for i in range(2):
    print("\nQUESTION 2:")
    answer = input("How many organ systems are in the human body? Please enter an integer: ").strip()

    if answer == "11":
        print("Correct, there are 11 organ systems in the body.")
        score += 1
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        if i == 1:
            print("Answer = 11.")
            break
        else:
            print("Second attempt.")

print("\nYou scored", score, "points.")
```

Output:

```
QUESTION 1:
Which of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state? Input a Letter A-E 
a) Anabolism
b) Catabolism
c) Tolerance
d) Homeostasis
e) Metabolism
Make your choice: b
False!
Second attempt.

QUESTION 1:
Which of the following terms describes the body's ability to maintain its normal state? Input a Letter A-E 
a) Anabolism
b) Catabolism
c) Tolerance
d) Homeostasis
e) Metabolism
Make your choice: d
Correct!

QUESTION 2:
How many organ systems are in the human body? Please enter an integer: 11
Correct, there are 11 organ systems in the body.

You scored 2.5 points.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is adding a half point every time they get it wrong, even if they don't get it right on the next try. So if they get it wrong twice, you'll give them a half point twice, which is the same as if they got it right.

You should only add to the score when they get the answer right. Then use the value of `tries` in an `if` statement to determine how much to add.

```
    if answer1 == "D" or answer1 == "d" :
        print("Correct!")
        if tries == 0:
            score += 1
        else:
            score += 0.5
        break
    else:
        print("False!")
```